# Behaviour of redis client-output-buffer-limit during resynchronization

Tags: redis

I'm assuming that during replica resynchronisation (full or partial), the master will attempt to send data as fast as possible to the replica. Wouldn't this mean the replica output buffer on the master would rapidly fill up since the speed the master can write is likely to be faster than the throughput of the network? If I have `client-output-buffer-limit` set for replicas, wouldn't the master end up closing the connection before the resynchronisation can complete?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Redis Master will close the connection and the synchronization will be started from beginning again. But, please find some details below:

1. Do you need to touch this configuration parameter and what is the purpose/benefit/cost of it?
2. There is a zero (almost) chance it will happen with default configuration and pretty much moderate modern hardware.
3. "By default normal clients are not limited because they don't receive data
   without asking (in a push way), but just after a request, so only asynchronous clients may create a scenario where data is requested faster than it can read." - the chunk from documentation .
4. Even if that happens, the replication will be started from beginning but it may lead up to infinite loop when slaves will continuously ask for synchronization over and over. Redis Master will need to fork whole memory snapshot (perform BGSAVE) and use up to 3 times of RAM from initial snapshot size each time during synchronization. That will be causing higher CPU utilization, memory spikes network utilization (if any) and IO.

General recommendations to avoid production issues tweaking this configuration parameter:

1. Don't decrease this buffer and before increasing the size of the buffer make sure you have enough memory on your box.
2. Please consider total amount of RAM as snapshot memory size (doubled for copy-on-write BGSAVE process) plus the size of any other buffers configured plus some extra capacity.

Please find more details [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/top-redis-headaches-for-devops-replication-buffer/)